# Equalizer in Free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, simplicial-stuff, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the free group generated by $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and for each $1\leq i\leq n$, let a homomorphism $d_i:F_n\to F_{n-1}$ be defined as follows:

- $d_i(x_r)=x_r$, if $i>r$;
- $d_i(x_r)=1$, if $i=r$;
- $d_i(x_r)=x_{r-1}$, if $i<r$.

The equalizer $E_n\leq F_n$ defined by $$E_n=\{x\in F_n\mid d_1(x)=d_2(x)=\cdots=d_n(x)\}$$ is clearly a subgroup of $F_n$, and thus a free group (Every subgroup of a free group is free).

**Question**: What is a minimal generating set of $E_n$?

---

My guess is the set consists of the following elements may be a (**Is it minimal?**) generating set; but I am not sure if it is correct:

1. $x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}$;
2. $[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}][x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(3)}]\cdots[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(n)}][x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(3)}]\cdots[x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(n)}]\cdots[x_{\sigma(n-1)},x_{\sigma(n)}]$;
3. $[[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_{\sigma(3)}][[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_{\sigma(4)}]\cdots[[x_{\sigma(n-2)},x_{\sigma(n-1)}],x_{\sigma(n)}]$;
4. $\cdots$;
5. $[\cdots[[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_{\sigma(3)}],\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}]$,

where $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$, the symmetric group acts on $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

**EDIT**: It was pointed out in the comment that the set I proposed is not a generating set; it is not even a subset of $E_n$ in general.

Comment: I don't think your elements are actually in $E_n$ unless $\sigma$ is either the identity or the order-reversing permutation.

Comment: @EricWofsey, you are exactly right!! If I restrict my $\sigma$ to the identity and order-reversing permutations, could the list be a generating set?

Comment: For $n=2$ your elements do not generate all of $E_2$; for instance, they do not generate $x_1^2x_2^2$.

Comment: Yes @EricWofsey, thanks!! Then is there any hope finding a minimal generating set of $E_n$?

Comment: It's not hard to show that $E_2$ is freely generated by the elements $x_1^kx_2^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, but things seem much more complicated for $n>2$.

Comment: Thanks @EricWofsey! If it is unknown for general $n$, would it be an interesting open problem?

Comment: This has been worked out by Jie Wu in ["Combinatorial description of homotopy groups of certain spaces"](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matwujie/newnewpis_3.pdf), see Theorem 3.4 there. Probably there are other versions too.

Comment: (Well in fact Wu has a free generating set for the intersection of the kernels of the $d_i$ but I think this can give what you need).

Comment: Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე for the reference! But I do not see how Wu's result answer my question.

Comment: Wu has free generators for the kernel of $E_n\to F_{n-1}$; it is true that one still has to determine the image, but I think this also can be done using Wu's calculations.

Comment: More about the image - it is the intersection of the diagonal $F_{n-1}\subset F_{n-1}^n$ with the image of $(d_1,...,d_n):F_n\to F_{n-1}^n$ and I believe one can compute it using known methods.

Comment: Decided to sketch Wu's construction since it is technical and in fact the idea is very simple. The kernel is generated by all those commutators which nontrivially involve all variables. To find free generating subset of such commutators, pass to the associated Lie ring which is the free Lie ring on $n$ generators. There are several known monomial bracket bases of free Lie rings (Lyndon, Shirshov, etc.) and one then just has to take the subset of one of these bases consisting of those brackets which involve each variable at least once.